# What's the best way to call multiple async tasks in a Web API controller?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I'm trying to find the best way to make my API async with multiple dependent calls

```
<top routes...>
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post()
{
    /*... some sync items*/
    int userId= await _ef.saveUser();
    var siteInfo = callsite(userId);
    return await _ef.updateUserLastModified(); //need to wait for other 2
}
```

So all 3 need to go in order, can I make a private function that runs that as a task?   Are there any advantages to make it async?  I basically just want it to thread those 3 calls.

Comment: Just put that 3 calls in a task.

Comment: Are three calls dependent on each other ?

Comment: Nothing wrong with this code. Clean and straight forward, except the first await should be in front of _ef.

Comment: Yes, I need the userId and the callsite() needs to be executed before updateUserLastModified()

Comment: edit the away before

Comment: I think I need to put the 3 calls in a task because the 2nd call I'm inserting into an oracle 3rd party db, and I don't have an await function for it.  So like said above it's probably better to make a task

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have is fine! Assuming the last line depends on the first two, your code is the correct way to await asynchronous calls and also execute synchronous code:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post()
{
   int userId = await _ef.saveUser();         // 1
   var siteInfo = callsite(userId);           // 2 
   return await _ef.updateUserLastModified(); // 3
}
```

Line 2 will not execute until line 1 is complete, and then line 3 will be awaited and return. Any synchronous code before the end of the method will also be executed "normally".

Async isn't the same thing as multithreading - it's just a way of telling the compiler that you need to wait for some asynchronous thing to finish before continuing.

Comment: So it's better then to make another function so the 2nd part is also under async.

Comment: @DanParker Line 2? No, unless that is inherently asynchronous code (and an awaitable Task), there's no reason to refactor it to "match" the async calls. Everything will work fine as it is.

Answer (score 2):

The beauty of `async` and `await` is that you can write your code such that it reads like synchronous code. Let's break down what you have, as it is the correct implementation of asynchronous programming.

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post()
{
   int userId = await _ef.saveUser();
   var siteInfo = callsite(userId);
   return await _ef.updateUserLastModified();
}
```

**Method Signature**

We define our publically accessible `async` method, that happily returns a `Task<IHttpActionResult>` and is named `Post`, great.

**Body Line 1**

We then are declaring and assigning a variable named `userId` the awaited result of the `_ed.saveUser()` invocation. This means that `saveUser` must return an `Task<int>`, otherwise this wouldn't compile. The `await` keyword is possible in this method block since we have used the `async` keyword in the method signature. When we `await` the `saveUser` call the internal async state-machine captures a return location and then immediately returns control to the calling thread -- allowing it to do work elsewhere. After some unknown amount of time, and when the saving of the user is complete control is then resuming where it left off (potentially on the same thread or even on a thread pool thread) and the `userId` variable is assigned.

**Body Line 2**

Once we have our `userId` then and only then do we continue to the next line. If we mistakenly omitted the `await` on the previous line and errantly declared our `userId` variable as a `var` instead of an `int`, it would have been problematic as the variable would have been a `Task<int>` rather than the materialized `int` we desired. Notice, this is synchronous code -- which is perfectly fine and acceptable and in fact encouraged. Not every piece of logic needs to be `async`, and the phrase "async all the way" actually means something else. It means, for example that instead of our `Post` method being `void` and calling `.Result` on `saveUser` you instead go async all the way.

**Body Line 3**

Finally, we are returning the awaited result of the `_ef.udateUserLastModified()` method. We know that this too returns a `Task<IHttpActionResult>`.